# How to avoid creating a new instance when clicking a page again and again in flutter?

Tags: flutter, stack, flutter-layout, state, dart-pub

I have a flutter app with a navigation drawer. It has three routes that redirect to the respective screens. But when I click on a particular screen that I am currently at, the new instance of that screen is created repeatedly. I don't want the current selected page's instance to be created again and again. Take an example of Gmail's navigation drawer. When I click on the selected page, it doesn't create a new instance. I want to have that functionality. Can anyone help me with this?

```
class NavList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavListState createState() => _NavListState();
}

class _NavListState extends State<NavList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.70, //70% of the screen
        child: Column(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/orange.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )),
                    arrowColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[700],
                    accountName: Text(''),
                    accountEmail: Text( 
                      'username@gmail.com',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 22.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[700],
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade300,
                    title: Text('Sellers'),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, SellerScreen.id);
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, SellerScreen.id);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade300,
                    title: Text('Shops'),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.shop),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ShopScreen.id);
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ShopScreen.id);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade300,
                    title: Text('Orders'),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, OrderScreen.id);
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, OrderScreen.id);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    hoverColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade300,
                    title: Text('Logout'),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Version 1.0.1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this code in onTap section:

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name != '/second'
                ? Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/second')
                : print('You can not push this page again');
```

This code compares name of the current page and the new page. if they were the same, it prints the error and if they were not, it would push the new page and pop the previous page.